# What is Mac Addressing in terms of Networking

Tags: mac-address

I want to ask what does the term "Mac Addressing " mean ?

I know what is a Mac address ,but when we say for example that

> "one of the functions of Network Interface Card (NIC) is MAC
> Addressing "

what we really mean ? does it mean that the device is responsible for adding the mac addresses to the frames ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAC address is the "hardware" address of a NIC. It uses that address as source address for frames it sends, and only accepts frames that are destined for that address (plus broadcasts and possibly other MAC addresses it has been configured with).

The NIC is also the device that's forming the frames that run across the network.

Answer (score 2):

The quote is a clumsy attempt to say that the NIC is the hardware that actually transmits and receives the frames.  As such, it creates the frames when transmitting (using it's built-in address as the source).  For receiving, it determines if the frames are addressed to the device (NIC), ignoring frames that aren't.